# Javaでのループの回し方、組み合わせ方

Tags: java

ルールは以下に沿って作ることです。

今は100より上、または0より下の数字を入力された場合、プログラムを終了させることができずに困っています

> キーボードから数字をENDと入力されるまで入力させ、全てを掛け算した結果をまとめて表示してください。
>
> **条件**
>
> - 入力値は、0以上、100以下とする。
> - 連続で入力させるのは、最大5回とする。
> - ENDと入力されたら、5回未満の入力回数でも計算結果を表示する。
> - 計算結果は、ENDと入力されてからまとめて表示すること。

**現状のソースコード:**

```
public class MainkadaiEX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("キーボードから0以上100以下の数字を入力\n");
        System.out.print("最大連続入力回数は5回です:\n");
        String ass = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();//キーボードから入力する数字
        long num[] = { 1 };
        int cnt;//カウント
        for (cnt = 0; cnt != 4; cnt++) {
            if (ass.equals("END")) {
            } else {
                long henkan = Long.parseLong(ass);
                ass = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
                while (true) {
                    if ((henkan >= 0) && (henkan <= 100)) {
                        num[0] = num[0] * henkan;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("指定した数字範囲外の入力を確認");
                    }
                }

                System.out.printf("残りの入力可能回数は%d回です:\n", (4 - cnt));
                }
            }
        if ((cnt == 4) || (ass.equals("END"))) {
            System.out.println("計算結果は" + num[0] + "です");
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 0以下または100以上を入力した時、コード中の "指定した数字範囲外の入力を確認" という出力は実行されていますか？

Comment: @cubick♦︎ 実行されるのは2回目からなんです。1回目は、残りの入力回数が表示されます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

課題らしいのでヒントを。
"指定した数字範囲外の入力を確認"を出力した後に、whileループをどう抜けるかを考えるということでしょうね。